# When I open a form in Delphi, Is there a way to open the code (pas) by default, instead of design (dfm)?

Tags: delphi

I am having some problems in some components, and I want to disable their design time packages, I just enable when I need. When I open my code, that some times is togheter with the form, when I open in the IDE, I want to first open by default de code part of it, instead the form itself. Is there a option for it?

Comment: Simple answer: no

Comment: One option is to remove the troublesome components from the form(s) and instead create them in code at run-time.  I did it for one component long ago, even used a panel component as a placeholder to help with form layout and replaced it with the troublesome component at run-time.

Comment: @Brian Our code base is huge, this is something that is not worth.

Comment: How about telling more about "I am having some problems in some components"?

Comment: @Olivier I explain it in this issue: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-27975
Basically the IDE takes several minutes to open because the "inheritance" of our components, probably because of the Package Cache loading.

Comment: I have very little hope that Embarcadero will look at this, because my company already tried many times to talk to then, so I decided to take the other way and disable the design time components temporary

Comment: The page is not public. Did you ask a question on SO about that issue?

Comment: @Olivier I did not ask a question, just opened the issue. If you want to take a look on it, here is a link: https://www.evernote.com/l/AnMcC91eK7dInbrx0btMJ1qqSqerA4oEWuU/

Comment: If the IDE takes a long time to load, how will displaying the code by default change anything? Does it also take long to display a form that contains those components?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have something like 170 packages? That's a lot. I would suggest agglomerating them in order to reduce their number.

Comment: @Olivier No and no. I want to show the code by default because we are disabling by default the design time packages, and I did not want errors to show up when I open a form, if I just want to edit the code.

Comment: About the packages problem, the architecture of ours packages is not the root cause of the problem. It is a bad architecture, too much inheritance, bad but not necessary wrong. Its a legacy code, that does not worth change that much. The root cause of it is a performance bug in the IDE loading.

Comment: I am a bit amazed that there isn't an option to open the .pas file when double clicking on a form in the Project Manager. I find most of MY time is spent editing code, and much less on the user interface, because that is where my applications tend to have the most meat. On the other hand, there certainly are times when the opposite is true, in which case the "hard-coded" behavior is what I want! Just so surprised that this isn't an option...

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of IDE options allowing you to do this. But there are some ways you can work around the issue, though it is not as convenient as a specific option.

You could comment out the `{$R *.dfm}` directive when you don't want the form to open. Of course, compiling like this would cause application to fail creating the form at runtime.

So a more dynamic approach would be to wrap it in a conditional compilation.

```
{$IFDEF WHATEVER}
{$R *.dfm}
{$ENDIF}
```

According to some quick testing, this seems to work. Though, I'm not aware of any built-in conditions that says whether your are compiling or designing. So I'd guess the less error prone way to do it would be to pass -dWHATEVER to the "Additional options to pass to the compiler"

[image: Addtional options to pass to the compilter]

DISCLAIMER : I did *not* extensively test this. This may/may not cause issues further down the road.

Comment: This is going to make your project a nightmare to work with, in order to "solve" a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: Ken, I appreciate you answer, but I agree with David. Between stay with my problem (that exists for me) and do something like what you proposed (wich would make our project even more complex), I prefer do nothing. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Whether this solution is worse than the problem is an evaluation better left to the ones having problems and seeking a solution.

Comment: @KenBourassa Commenting is allowed here still, unless I am mistaken. I'm entitled to leave a comment expressing my opinion. You are under no obligation to agree with me. It's healthy when people disagree.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Not sure why you're so defensive.  I merely commented that I disagreed with your opinion, suggesting there are no problems where this solution wouldn't be helpful (and calling it a "nightmare" is overselling it seriously. I've had to work in way worse codebase.  That's a breeze). And beside... Commenting is still allowed here, I heard.

Comment: OK fine, I thought you were suggesting that it wasn't my place to evaluate this. That's all.